# How does Sinatra allow its syntax?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

One of Sinatra's examples is this:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  set :sessions, true
  set :foo, 'bar'

  get '/' do
    'Hello world!'
  end
end
```

How does Sinatra allow the " get '/' do" syntax? It doesn't seem to be a method, and I'm not aware of any other syntax that allows that.

Comment: What makes you think it's not a method? It's called exactly the same way as any other method, it looks exactly the same as any other method, it *is* in fact a method.

Comment: That it's inside of a class--in every other language I know, class bodies do not permit executable code, only member variables and method declarations. In what context, then, is all of that in-class code executed, and when?

Comment: Ruby allows for 'executable' code almost everywhere, including the class definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called an ["Internal Domain-Specific Language"](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/writing-a-domain-specific-language-in-ruby) in Ruby.  That `get` you are calling is actually a method, defined by Sinatra, that takes a block (which is your implementation of the get).

When you find yourself calling odd-looking methods, but still able to execute what seems like normal Ruby code, you're likely using an Internal DSL.  Examples include Bundler's Gemfiles, Rake's Rakefiles, RSpec specifications...

Answer (score 2):

The `get '/'` is specifying the GET endpoint for your application. If you were to start up the server and go to localhost:port/, then you would see 'Hello world!' on the page.

```
def get(path, opts = {}, &block)
  conditions = @conditions.dup
  route('GET', path, opts, &block)

  @conditions = conditions
  route('HEAD', path, opts, &block)
end
```

This is the get method in Sinatra's lib. The get method takes a path as an argument and will route you to that path. You can also pass in options (opts), but that isn't done in your example. The last argument is a block. This is the part between the do and end.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question--I was wondering *how* Sinatra allows that syntax, not what it does.

Comment: You beat me to it. See https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1366-L1374